# GRUB booting problem

Tags: 11.04, boot, windows-7, wubi, grub2

I'd Ubuntu 11.04 32 bit installed via wubi on windows 7 64 bit. The installation was a success. I'd either access Ubuntu, or windows 7 on the boot option of my computer. i made use of both OS for months until when i'd only access windows 7. whenever i click/select the Ubuntu tab, it goes straight to GRUB. Displaying;

*GRUB Version 1.98+20100804-5*
 Minimal BASH-like line editing........
GRUB> _

I'm a rookie at this.
Please help!

Comment: Looks like Grub is broken, you will have to reinstall it.

Comment: Warning - never reinstall grub on a Wubi install.

Answer (score 1):

The most likely cause of ending up at a grub prompt, is that the Wubi virtual disk has been corrupted i.e. the file `C:\ubuntu\disks\root.disk` (it may also be on a 'drive' other than C:) This can occur from performing hard shutdowns on your computer or power failures.

You should first run `chkdsk` on the drive that contains your Wubi install. Then you will need to confirm that the root.disk is still present or recover it from the \FOUND.000 directory that chkdsk recovers to.

Refer to this for specific instructions: http://ubuntu-with-wubi.blogspot.com/2011/08/missing-rootdisk.html

To avoid problems like this, avoid hard shutdowns - even if your Ubuntu install is hanging, try <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> to reboot safely.

Answer (score -2):

I think your grub is partially broken and it is easiest to install grub to correct the problem. Boot into ubuntu using liveCD. You can find a very detailed info on grub/grub2 in https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2 page.

Comment: This is a wubi install. Installing grub will damage windows and leave the computer unbootable (boots to a GRUB RESCUE> prompt). If you have already done this you will need to reinstall the windows bootloader.