# laptop doesn't boot, stops at GRUB screen

Tags: grub2, wubi, boot-failure

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I can't boot into a usable system anymore. What should I do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126724/i-cant-boot-into-a-usable-system-anymore-what-should-i-do)

I installed Ubuntu on a laptop's hard drive along with Microsoft Vista.  It was working perfectly, but a few days ago it stopped working.  I do not know what has happened....on starting it is showing the following screen:

```
GNU GRUB VERSION 1.99-12ubuntu5......
MINIMAL BASH-LIKE line editing is supported. FOR THE FIRST WORD, TAB LISTS POSSIBLE
COMMAND COMPLETIONS. ANYWHERE ELSE TAB POSSIBLE DEVICE OR FILE COMPLETIONS.
GRUB>
```

Comment: sory, i do not have live cd..as i have downloaded it from ubuntu's website..

Comment: it is a windows installer (.exe) wubi...

Comment: @harry  -- see if the linked 'possible duplicate' helps.  Are you able to make a LiveCD with a different computer?

Comment: harry, it's quite possible to recover this. This happens to Wubi installs where the root.disk is corrupted or missing. You can find more discussion here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/85268/grub-booting-problem (I mentioned this before but my comment was deleted).

Comment: I am doing something similar HERE!!! http://askubuntu.com/questions/366001/ubuntu-13-10-grub-2-0

Answer (score 1):

Boot the Ubuntu Live CD.

Press Ctrl-Alt-F1

login as root

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: These commands are incorrect for installing grub from a live CD. Also since this is a wubi install, it will stop the computer from booting. I can only -1 once though ;)

Comment: @bcbc: Or you can edit the answer or write a correct answer...

Comment: @naught101 or...